# How do I change this QuerySet to have this JSON data output

Tags: python, json, django

From my current query:

```
response_data = {}
response_data["medium"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects = getgeom_medium).values('brgy_locat').annotate(countmedium = Count('brgy_locat')))
response_data["high"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects = getgeom).values('brgy_locat').annotate(counthigh = Count('brgy_locat')))
response_data["low"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects = getgeom_low).values('brgy_locat').annotate(countlow = Count('brgy_locat')))

result = {}
for category in response_data.values(): 
  for element in category: 
    key = element.pop('brgy_locat')
        if key not in result: result[key] = {
            "loc": key
    }
    result[key].update(element)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type = 'application/json')
```

The JSON output is this:

```
{
    "Mabini": {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "loc": "Mabini",
        "countmedium": 2,
        "countlow": 25
    },
    "Barangay 12": {
        "loc": "Barangay 12",
        "countlow": 29
    },
    "Katugasan": {
        "loc": "Katugasan",
        "countlow": 3
    }
}
```

But I wanted to have this output instead:

```
{
    "0": {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "loc": "Mabini",
        "countmedium": 2,
        "countlow": 25
    },
    "1": {
        "loc": "Barangay 12",
        "countlow": 29
    },
    "2": {
        "loc": "Katugasan",
        "countlow": 3
    }
}
```

I'm new to Django and Python, I tried looping and used a variable to be the index, but the output changes and I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at django rest framework. http://www.django-rest-framework.org

Comment: Haven't tried using that. I'm new with Django although I developed an app before but that was simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another simple transformation of the result:

```
json_result = {str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(result.values())}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_result), content_type='application/json')
```

**UPDATE**: The order of the keys in the dict is not guaranteed.  But if you want to get the exact output of the JSON then you can use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) of the python 2.7:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
json_result = OrderedDict((str(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(result.values()))
```

Comment: The result doesn't start with 0.

Comment: Sure. Usually there is no much sense of the ordered keys of the dict.  But if you really want it then use the `OrderedDict`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is changing because you are using dictionary to store the keys. Dictionaries don't keep the order of their elements (*they are unordered*), its better for you to use python lists instead when you want keep the order of the elements.

E.g.

```
results = []
#...
results.append(...)
```